# Functions in sh shell

Tags: arrays, bash, function, sh

Do functions not exist in the sh shell? I am trying to convert a bash script to also run in sh and I'm having trouble dumbing down the code. Without functions and arrays, its become difficult to replicate the scripts functionality. Ideally I want to write one script that will run in either shell, not two slightly similar scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are functions in `sh`, but the `function` keyword is missing. Define your functions as

```
frobnicate () {
# ....
}
```

With arrays, you are out of luck.

Comment: Ah sorry, I misunderstood. This solution does work in both bash and sh, thank you.